# Using cookie to authenticate into frontend in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token

So I have a login controller that creates and responds with a cookie.

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {

        try {
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            ]);

            $user = User::where('email', $validatedData['email'])->first();

            if (!$user || !Hash::check($validatedData['password'], $user->password)) {
                throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                    'email' => ['Invalid credentials'],
                ]);
            }

            $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $e->errors()], 422);
        }
        $cookie = cookie('auth_token', $token, 60 * 24 * 7);
        return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'token' => $token], 201)->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

On my web.php I have a custom middleware

```
Route::middleware([EnsureTokenIsValid::class])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

And my custom middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if ($request->hasCookie('auth_token')) {
            $token = $request->cookie('auth_token');
            error_log($token);
        }
        if (!$request->hasCookie('auth_token')) {
            error_log("No cookie");
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

The output in the terminal is always

> WARN  No cookie.

What's going wrong? The cookie is correctly set in the browser every time I successfully log in. Why is the cookie not being sent in the request? And how do I decrypt this cookie in my custom middleware?

Comment: Is your frontend using any of the frontend frameworks?

Comment: No, it is using none.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the cookie, set its path to `/` so that it's available across your entire domain.

```
$cookie = cookie('auth_token', $token, 60 * 24 * 7, '/');
```